# Update multiple rows also single row using textarea with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I want to update three textarea values to the database with a single submit button. But It is not working for me. When I try to update a single textarea then the value is updated to the database correctly, But when I add other two textareas, again it is not working. Other two textareas getting blank values.I know it is a basic question. But this drives me insane. Would anybody please help me to achieve this?

Here is my database table which name is optional and it has some default values:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/afhXJ.png

Here is my three text areas which read the options table default values. When enter a new text it will then insert into the options table according to the option name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUFrW.png

Here is my HTML code:

```html
<form name="settings" role="form" method="post" action="bangla_insert_submit.php">

    <h5>Insert Bangla Head Here:</h5>
    <textarea name="bangla_head" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
    <h5>Insert Chamber Head Here:</h5>
    <textarea name="chamber_head" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
    <h5>Insert English Head Here:</h5>
    <textarea name="english_head" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Here is my submited file code.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
    $bangla_head  = $_POST['bangla_head'];
    $chamber_head = $_POST['chamber_head'];
    $english_head = $_POST['english_head'];

    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT option_id, option_name, option_value FROM options" );

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        if (isset($_POST['bangla_head']) && $row['option_name'] == 'bangla_head'){

            //If the option is now yes (isset checks returns true if the box is selected) and the option in the db is N then update.
            mysql_query( "UPDATE options SET option_value = '$bangla_head' WHERE  option_id ='20' ");
        }
        if (isset($_POST['chamber_head']) && $row['option_name'] == 'chamber_head'){

            //If the option is now yes (isset checks returns true if the box is selected) and the option in the db is N then update.
            mysql_query( "UPDATE options SET option_value = '$chamber_head' WHERE  option_id ='21' ");
        }
        if (isset($_POST['english_head']) && $row['option_name'] == 'english_head'){

            //If the option is now yes (isset checks returns true if the box is selected) and the option in the db is N then update.
            mysql_query( "UPDATE options SET option_value = '$english_head' WHERE  option_id ='22' ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using if(!empty($value)) { 

It could do wonders.

Comment: Please add the html code also, are you trying to submit all these three textarea values from one form?

Comment: Yes I am trying to submit all these textarea values from one form.

Comment: My previous code also working fine. The problem is when I try to insert single textarea then my others two textarea also updated with nothing. Please check this image then you will understand: http://i.imgur.com/SUgkCqp.png

Comment: @Dinidu I have added the HTML code. Would you please check this.

Comment: It works for me. When i add an echo for all variables. Then they return the values for each text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (isset($_POST['bangla_head']) && ($_POST['bangla_head']!='') )
```

isset() checks if a variable has a value including ( False , 0 , or empty string), but not NULL. Returns TRUE if variable exists otherwise returns FALSE.

Comment: But previous code also working fine. The problem is when I try to insert single textarea then my others two textarea also updated with nothing. Please check this image then you will understand: http://i.imgur.com/SUgkCqp.png

Comment: You need to check value is blank or not isset checks if a variable has a value including ( False , 0 , or empty string) .and also use else.
`if (isset($_POST['bangla_head']) && ($_POST['bangla_head']!='') ) { //your code } else if(second condition) { }. `

Answer (score 0):

You must put validation for blank fields.

Write your code by this way:-

```
$bangla_head  = $_POST['bangla_head'];
$chamber_head = $_POST['chamber_head'];
$english_head = $_POST['english_head'];    


 $arr = [
    '20'=>$bangla_head,
    '21'=>$chamber_head,
    '22'=>$english_head
 ];

 foeach($arr as $key => $value){
     mysql_query( "UPDATE options SET option_value = '$value' WHERE  option_id =$key ");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. When I update three textarea at a time it updates sucessfully. But when I update a single textarea then the other two textarea field gets bank. Also when I update two textarea then it other field gets blank. Please check this screenshot then you will understand - http://i.imgur.com/SUgkCqp.png

Comment: I am not able to put the validation for empty field. I'm still a beginner at PHP so I'm not really sure how to do it. I know where I am going wrong with the PHP, I just don't know a way around it. Please help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Please check the screenshot which I have posted in my previous comment then you will understand the actual problem.

Comment: Please refer this link. it will help you to understand validations. http://www.w3schools.in/php/form-validation/

Comment: Thank you for the link. The link is really usefull for me. Would you please check my first comment with the screenshot?